# Flair HTML snippet refers to HTTP image src, causes mixed content warning on HTTPS site

Tags: bug, flair, ssl

I used the Flair HTML snippet from my profile settings on my website, but I noticed that it caused Chrome to report a mixed content warning. It turns out that the image `src` is pointing to an `HTTP` resource, not an `HTTPS` one.

I updated my snippet code and all is good now, but the code should be like this by default.

[image]