# Links on the user page are HTTP, not HTTPS

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks, ssl

When you visit your user page at `https://stackexchange.com/users/<ID>/<NAME>` (note `HTTPS`, secure connection), the links (e.g., top questions and answers) take you to the HTTP (not HTTPS!) locations.

My experience with other sites created an expectation that once I land in a secure area, I only leave it by an explicit request and with a warning, so the current behavior looks like a bug to me.

It appears that I am not the first to notice this shortcoming.
Other sites appear to make faster progress on this. SE is the premier technology site on the internet, and it seems to be struggling with a technical issue for years. Isn't this weird?

Related:

- [Flair HTML snippet refers to HTTP image src, causes mixed content warning on HTTPS site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290763/215439)
- [Permalink short URLs lose HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223728/215439)
- [HTTPS-only images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343276/215439)
- [HTTPS protocol does not carry over when visiting metas or chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274447/215439)
- [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/215439)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images

Comment: One thing - you are describing the current state of affairs, but nowhere do you explain why this is a bug. Why do you believe this to be a bug?

Comment: @Oded: My experience with other sites created an expectation that once I land in a secure area, I only leave it by an explicit request and with a warning.

Comment: @sds as Nick says in the old bug report, Stack Exchange still does not support HTTPS. It's in progress for years, but might just take few more years to complete. Until then, those link would still be http only, I'm afraid.